# ¿Hay algún antónimo para "envidiar"?

Tags: traducción, verbos, solicitud-de-término, antónimos

En el periódico El País publicaron un artículo un poco pijotero llamado
[*Seis palabras imposibles de traducir al español*](https://elpais.com/elpais/2017/03/11/ciencia/1489251890_335686.html), el típico *clickbait* (¿o [*cazaclics*](https://twitter.com/javipalarcon/status/959372129593683970)?) con el que obtener visitas.

Pues bien, resulta que el artículo contiene, efectivamente, una lista de palabras de otros idiomas cuya traducción literal parece bastante complicada.

Me llamó la atención el siguiente término alemán:

> **Gönnen**: término alemán antónimo exacto de «envidiar».

Si observamos la definición del término en el DLE, vemos que es:

> [**envidiar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Fsk9IJc)
>
> 1. tr. Tener envidia de alguien o de algo, dolerse del bien ajeno.
> 2. tr. Desear o apetecer algo que tienen otros.

Es decir, que tanto habla del deseo de algo material como espiritual (a saber, tener algo pero también que algo no le vaya bien a alguien). Esa dualidad hace complicada la búsqueda de un contrario: ¿queremos buscar el contrario de la parte espiritual o de la material?

Google Translate dice que su traducción literal sería *conceder* y [Word Reference](http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/envidia) recoge *indiferencia* y *conformidad* como posibles antónimos de *envidia*.

No sé, siento que algo falta. ¿A alguien se le ocurre algún término que sea tan contundente como *envidiar*?

Comment: no creo que conceptos tan complejos tengan un solo antónimo, las emociones y actitudes humanas no se mesen en un sojo eje

Comment: @fedorqui ,  tu pregunta me confunde,  preguntas si hay algun antonimo para envidiar, o la traduccion de gonnen o si hay palabras sin "antonimos" con envidiar ?

Comment: Coincido con lo que dice el artículo: "Cada idioma tiene vocablos que no se pueden trasladar a otras lenguas." Parece ser el caso. El mejor antónimo de *envidiar* o *ser envidioso* es, para mí, *no envidiar* o *no ser envidioso*.

Comment: @Mike pregunto si hay algún antónimo de _envidiar_. Si no queda claro el enunciado, siéntete libre de [edit]arlo.

Comment: @fedorqui No tengo nada que editar en tu pregunta. Simplemente expresé mi opinión de que, a veces, las palabras no tienen antónimos y la negación es la mejor forma de expresar el contrario.

Comment: @Gustavson ya, se lo decía a Mike...

Comment: No sé, para mí un antónimo sería más en plan *repudiar*, igual que diríamos que *triste* es antónimo de *feliz*, y no una palabra que meramente significa *no feliz*.

Comment: Podría ser desear a alguien algo, p.ej. te deseo lo mejor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El ejemplo de uso que da Wiktionary para [*gönnen*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/g%C3%B6nnen) es:

> *Sie hatten so viel Pech im Leben; ich **gönne** ihnen den Lottogewinn.*

Donde el verbo alemán es transitivo y el objeto directo es aquello de lo que se tiene lo contrario de envidia.
Este uso transitivo es el mismo que encontramos en español para el verbo "envidiar", donde el OD es aquello que se envidia: *Envidio su peinado*.

En traducción libre, el ejemplo en alemán viene a querer decir lo siguiente:

> Han tenido muy mala suerte en la vida; (yo) **`<verbo>`** que hayan ganado la Lotería.
>   <sub><sub>Los alemanes son muy de montar sustantivos largos para nombrar conceptos. *Lottogewinn* viene a ser "el acto de ganar la Lotería" pero nadie lo diría así en español.</sub></sub>

Donde `<verbo>` sería la traducción buscada.

Lo normal e idiomático en esa frase sería usar decir "**me alegra**" o "**me alegro de**":

> Han tenido muy mala suerte en la vida; **me alegra** que hayan ganado la Lotería.

Con lo cual la traducción sería la forma pronominal del verbo **alegrar**:

> [**alegrarse**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1hHpisE#0kKTVns)
>
> 7. prnl. Recibir o sentir alegría.

Pero alguien podría argumentar que no valen formas pronominales, porque no aceptan objeto directo y porque para usarlas es necesario añadir un sufijo al verbo y eso es trampa (?).
Podríamos usar entonces el verbo **gozar**:

> [**gozar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JNbAlxi)
>
> 1. tr. Sentir placer o alegría a causa de algo. *Gozó la vista del mar*.
>   4. intr. Sentir placer o alegría por algo o por alguien. *Gozamos CON su compañía*. U. t. c. prnl.

Este verbo significa literalmente "alegrarse por algo" y además se puede usar tanto de manera transitiva como intransitiva, lo cual lo acerca un poco más al uso del *gönnen* germano.
La oración quedaría así:

> Han tenido muy mala suerte en la vida; **gozo** (con) que hayan ganado la Lotería.

Answer (score 3):

**Según** el compendio de vicios y virtudes del cristianismo, la virtud de la cual carecen los envidiosos y contrarresta la envida es el de la **Caridad**.

En lugar de desear la prosperidad de los demás, deseamos que sean prósperos y les brindamos nuestro apoyo para alcanzar dicha prosperidad.

También aparecen la benevolencia/amabilidad/bondad.

Pero específicamente es el deseo de ayudar a los demás.

---

La otra opción es el enorgullecimiento de las acciones de los demás.

---

Edit

Debatir por qué caridad es el opuesto a la envidia sería un tema laaaaaaaaaargo,  y como dice la pregunta: los alemanes tienen una palabra que es todo lo contrario a eso. El español no la tiene, hay muchas palabras que se presentan de esta manera y es debido a que son palabras con un significado ideológico se vuelve aun mas difícil traducirlas o invertirlas .

**¿Quién me puede decir el antónimo de beber?, ¿será escupir?, ¿será vomitar de verdad el antónimo de comer?**

Si no tenemos la palabra, deberíamos crearla o definirla, si una palabra no capturara el significado, una frase si:

El antónimo de la Envidia es la alegría por el éxito del otro.

Comment: Estoy intentando ver por qué la caridad es lo opuesto de la envidia. Creo que son dos cosas que no tienen nada que ver la una con la otra. Me explico: la caridad se aplica a aquellos que sientes que son más desafortunados que tú (como cuando le das limosna a alguien), mientras que la envidia se aplica a aquellos que sientes que son más afortunados que tú (como cuando a alguien le toca la lotería y a ti no). Con respecto a quien le toca la lotería nunca vas a sentir caridad. Puede que alegría, indiferencia o incluso pena. Pero no caridad.

Comment: Y en todo caso, recuerda que estamos en un foro de lengua. Consideraría un despropósito que alguien te votara negativo simplemente por mostrar sentimientos religiosos, así que procura no tomarlo como una ofensa hacia tus creencias, que son tan respetables como las de cualquiera, sino más bien como un indicador de que la respuesta puede ser incorrecta desde el punto de vista del lenguaje.

Comment: @Charlie: La 8ª acepción de caridad en el DLE es: 8. f. Rel. **Virtud cristiana opuesta a la envidia** y a la animadversión.  Es decir, desde el punto de vista religioso cristiano , según la RAE,  la caridad es lo opuesto de la envidia

Comment: @walen: ¡Que yo solo citaba al DLE!

Comment: editare mi respuesta tambien que tambien respondera a los comentarios

Comment: En realidad no usaría ninguna de las respuestas propuestas como antónimo de envidiar, pero como discusión valiosa y aporte al sitio, le he dado +1 a las dos respuestas. Los dos argumentos son interesantes así en la práctica sean difíciles de usar sin tener que dar explicación.

Comment: Otro ejemplo en el que la definición de una virtud cristiana y el concepto usualmente entendido por el mismo vocablo discrepan grandemente es el de ***Humildad*** usualmente se asume que alguien humilde es necesariamente de escasos recursos o sin grandes aspiraciones, sin embargo en la definición cristiana quién es humilde se conoce a sí mismo y asume sus virtudes tanto como acepta sus limitaciones y por ello brinda y exige en justa medida lo que le corresponde, no más  no menos en yuxtaposición al soberbio que se engaña a sí mismo y a los demás adjudicándose mucho más de lo que es y merece.

Answer (score 2):

¿No tendría sentido que el antónimo de envidiar fuese admirar, al menos en una de sus acepciones?

Envidia: "Tristeza o pesar del bien ajeno".

Admirar: "Ver, contemplar o considerar con estima o agrado especiales a alguien o algo que llaman la atención por cualidades juzgadas como extraordinarias".

Answer (score 1):

Agrego a estas muy buenas respuestas una que es otra forma posible para la frase aludida (en el sentido de "alegrarse" genuinamente por alguien —en lugar de albergar envidia)

> Han tenido muy mala suerte en la vida; (yo) *me **regocijo*** [o ***complazco***] en el que hayan ganado la Lotería.

Answer (score 0):

En base a https://german.stackexchange.com/q/23604/16947:

*Solidarizarse, por solidaridad quisiera que, me daría gusto que algo pasara, me alegra que, no tomarlo mal, reconocer.*

Ejemplos:

> Me daría gusto que se ganara la lotería.
>
> Me alegro por su aceptación a Harvard.
>
> No me lo tomarán mal si me tomo una copa después del examen, ¿verdad?
>
> La maestra reconoció que contestó correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Algo bastante bastante contrario a la  envidia, es el desprendimiento y la generosidad. No significan exactamente «no sentir envidia», pero si *realmente* no tienes ningún apego por algo, o te place darlo *realmente* a cambio de nada, no puedes sentir envidia de que alguien más lo tenga. Simplemente imposible.